# How to delete second duplicates from postgres with uuid id?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I need to delete duplicates by two fields (name and address) from DB.
But only second rows must be deleted as the value for this field is different.
The DB looks like this:

```
id   name   address   value  
...  name1  address1  value1
...  name1  address1  value2
...  name2  address2  value3
...  name2  address2  value4
```

The result after deleting must look like this:

```
id   name   address   value  
...  name1  address1  value1
...  name2  address2  value3
```

The problem is that my id type is UUID and I can't do something like

```
Delete from DB
where id not in( select min(id) from DB
group by name, address);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: SQL data is not ordered, so you will need to define what you consider a second row? Since you chose to use a pseudo random PK(I do not understand the trend to using UUIDs for this) that is out. So unless you have some other way to create an ordering e.g. an insert timestamp then I don't see that this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have chosen a pseudo random identifier does not mean you cannot use it as a discriminator. It is still a unique value. The below uses the Postgres `distinct on` clause to select the identifiers to keep, then deletes rows not in the list on selected. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7f8be40e326b33bd8987f2f8c295b723))

```
with keepers(id) as 
     ( select distinct on (name, address) id 
         from db
        order by name, address, value
     ) 
delete from db 
 where id not in (select id from keepers);
```

NOTE: The CTE could have been written as the sub-select in your delete statement.

Comment: This assumes facts not in evidence, namely that `...order by name, address, value...` is actually the order desired. Given that the OP was wanting something like: `select min(id) from DB group by name, address` I'm thinking they want ordering by sequence of insertion.